# How to add a UIView into another UIView at the bottom

Tags: ios, uiview, uikit

How do you insert a UIView into a UILabel?

**Goal:**

Make a separate UIView the background of an existing UI component.

**Example**

```
    //Views
    let viewOne = UIImageView(); //bottom view, e.g. a UIImageView
    let viewTwo = UILabel();     //top view, e.g. a UILabel

    //Traditional
    self.addSubview(viewOne);
    self.addSubview(viewTwo);   //viewTwo goes on top 

    //Target
    viewTwo.addSubview(viewOne);
    self.addSubview(viewTwo;    //goal is to encapsulate viewOne into viewTwo
```

**Question**

How do you insert viewOne into the bottom of viewTwo? Do you use a layer of viewOne, I can't seem to get this successful!

Comment: Use the proper initializer that takes a frame. Add constraints as needed.

Comment: heh? I specifically am trying to apply an image AND a background color to a UILabel, your answer doesn't apply here?

Comment: Of course my comment applies. Creating views with the proper initializer helps. And using constraints also sizes and positions the views properly.

Comment: rmaddy I do not understand your reference here, please see my posted resolution below for illustration of how I see to accomplish UIView integration using Adam's recommendations. Please elaborate further so we can understand your intent better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a general rule, you should not use UIKit classes in un-documented or unexpected ways if it can be avoided. In this case, you don't know if `UILabel` expects a specific set of subviews, or if it depends on the order of those subviews.

The correct way to do this is to make new `UIView` subclass that contains both views as *it's own* subviews. This way, you can control the view order, position, etc without worrying about how `UILabel` internals may change in the future.

Answer (score 0):

thank you Adam, I used this for solution. For reference here is my solution:

```
class TexturedLabel :  NSObject {
    var label     : UILabel;
    var imageView : UIImageView;

    override init() {
        label     = UILabel();
        imageView = UIImageView();
        super.init();
        imageView.image = UIImage(named:"textured");  /* grab texture img                                   */
        imageView.contentMode = .topLeft;             /* place the image in the upper left corner unscaled  */
        imageView.clipsToBounds = true;               /* constrain image to frame boundaries                */
    }

    func text(_ text:String)                            { label.text = text; }
    func font(_ font:UIFont?)                           { label.font = font; }
    func color(_ color:UIColor)                         { imageView.backgroundColor = color;
    func frame(_ frame:CGRect)                          { label.frame = frame; imageView.frame = frame; }    
    func textColor(_ textColor:UIColor)                 { label.textColor = textColor; }
    func textAlignment(_ textAlignment:NSTextAlignment) { label.textAlignment = textAlignment; }
    func numberOfLines(_ numberOfLines:Int)             { label.numberOfLines = numberOfLines; }
    func lineBreakMode(_ lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakMode) { label.lineBreakMode = lineBreakMode; }

    func addToView(_ view : UIView) {
        view.addSubview(self.imageView);
        view.addSubview(self.label);
    }
}
```

Thank you so much Adam!!